# Ошибка: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

Выводится ошибка: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
В чем смысл данной ошибки?
А если объявить функцию без прототипа, тогда всё нормально.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

//вывод элементов двумерного массива в консоль

void outputArray (int); 

int main(){

int arrayTest [3][3] = {
{0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0}
};

outputArray (arrayTest); // На этой строке метка об ошибке

return 0;

}

void outputArray (int arr[][3]){
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cout << arr[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас первое объявление прототипа:

```
void outputArray (int);
```

никак не совпадает со вторым определением, которое должно дать тело:

```
void outputArray (int arr[][3]){
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cout << arr[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
 }
}
```

Чтобы компилятор вас понял, заголовки прототипа и реализации должны совпадать - сверху должно быть

```
void outputArray (int arr[][3]);
```